# Trouble with google sheet Utilities.parseCsv app script

Tags: csv, parsing, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have a google appt script running that i use to get a CSV from an email and put into google sheets.

```
function importCSVFromGmail() {
    var threads = GmailApp.search("from:myemail@gmail.com");
    var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
    var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
    attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();  
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
        var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");
        sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
        sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
    }
}
```

It runs smoothly most times, but occasionally if the source file contains semi-colons ';' anywhere in the body of the text strings, it fails and is unable to parse the file, with an error here:

```
Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");
```

is there a way to either find and replace all instances of semi-colon with something like '$' using a batch file or something, or better yet, just a way to ignore the character in the app script I'm running?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Please post a full example that demonstrates the issue, e.g. : ```function worksFine(){ var csv = 'Header1,Header2\nr1c1,r1c2\nr2;c1;,r2c2\nr3c1,r3c2;\nr4c1,r4c2'; Logger.log(Utilities.parseCsv(csv)); }``` You even forgot to mention what the error you're receiving is =/

Answer (score 0):

thanks i was able to have the people generating the source file clean up their outputs, so no longer an issue.